# ASP.Net Web API - Display HTML and download file

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

In our AngularJS / ASP.Net WebAPI application, we need to generate a PDF file when clicking a button. The button re-directs the user to the following URL on a **new** browser page:

`xyz.com/api/getpdf?Token=f3Ttkwf5XyvvZwcOZpEz`

`getpdf` is a API that returns the PDF file or an HTML error code if an error occurs.

The problem is that the PDF can take up to 30 seconds to generate. How can I display some HTML on the page (informing user to wait) before I send the file? The HTML should also be returned in the same API call. I've read that it is possible to have **multiple responses on one request**. But how do I do this?

This is the simplified code in the controller to return the PDF:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPDF(string Token)
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp = null;
    try
    {         
        // Generate PDF
        Byte[] lPDF = GetPDF(Token);

        // Return PDF in response
        resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        resp.Content = new ByteArrayContent(lPDF);
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "PDF-File.pdf";
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentLength = lPDF.Length;

        return resp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toolkit.LogError("GetPDF", ex);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overlay on the previous page.

For example you have a button who call your controller's method, on click on this button display your overlay with the message 'Loading'.

When the document will be generated, the page will be redirected and the overlay will disappear.

**Example with JQuery**

```js
$("#generate").click(function(){
  $(".overlay").show();
  setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com"},2000);
});
```

```css
.overlay{
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay">Loading...</div>
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
```

Here the setTimeout method is just used for simulate a time of response.

Comment: That is nice - but I cannot fix the time at a specific interval - it may take 5 seconds or it may take 30 seconds. And I would need the "waiting for file" message on the new page so the user can continue working on the application.

Comment: Yeah it's just an example, in your case you don't need to call the hide method if the page is redirect. You just need to call it if you're using with ajax method for generate your document. Here i can change the time of response (in the settimeout) to 30sec...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you may generate pdf-file in two steps.
First step is to ask web server to generate pdf-file. (POST-request)
Second step is to ask web server if pdf-file is already generated. (GET-request or SignalR)

Comment: Yes, that would be easy to do - but what I wanted was to do it in one request.